# Upgrade to 12.04 from Natty?

Tags: 11.04, 12.04, update-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I skip over releases?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases)

I'm trying to upgrade to Precise, i'm on Natty now.
Tried [This guide](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade) to upgrade, but the update manager only lets me upgrade to 11.10. 
Tried also to check "Only LTS relases" on the settings. 
So, how to upgrade directly from Natty? 
//TheGatorade